# Updating remote view with dynamic value throws an error

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, linked-server

I have an updatable view (vwItem) being accessed via a linked server ([sql\dev].)

When I update the view with a static data, the underlying table gets updated.

> UPDATE    ci SET      CertifiedNumber = '44444' 
>   FROM  [sql\dev].contact.dbo.vwItem ci WITH (NOLOCK)
>   WHERE ci.CertifiedBatchID IN ( 5829 )

But when I try to pass a dynamic value,

> declare @lo_vch_CertifiedNumber varchar(50) =
>   '1111111111222222222233333' 
>   UPDATE    ci 
>   SET       CertifiedNumber = @lo_vch_CertifiedNumber + '44444' 
>   FROM  [sql\dev].contact.dbo.vwItem ci
>   WITH (NOLOCK) 
>   WHERE ci.CertifiedBatchID IN ( 5829 )

it fails, with following error message

> The statement has been terminated.
>  Msg 16932, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1
>  The cursor has a FOR UPDATE list and the requested column
>   to be updated is not in this list.

I don't even use a cursor but the error mentions a cursor..

Here is the definition of "vwItem".

> CREATE view [dbo].vwItem 
>   with schemabinding
>   AS
>     select  CertifiedItemID = cast(CertifiedItemID as varchar),
>             CertifiedNumber, [Service], Weight, Price, CertifiedBatchID
>     from    dbo.tblItem (nolock)

Why does the error occur and what does it mean?

Comment: I know this isn't the same thing exactly, but it sounds like its related to your issue. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2520691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got around the problem by implementing a sproc that updates vwItem instead of using updatable view